# Continuity condition for induced topology

Tags: general-topology

I have a slight confusion regarding the topology induced by a map $f: X \to (Y, \tau_Y)$.

By definition $\tau_X = \{f^{-1}[U] : U \in \tau_Y \}$ and so we’re generating the topology on $X$ using open sets in $Y$. However this doesn’t imply that $f^{-1}[U]$’s would be neccessarily open in $X$ right? I’m not assuming anything related to the continuity of $f$ yet, but wouldn’t this contradict the fact that the sets in $\tau_X$ are defined to be open?

In essence what is the key here that guarantees that $f^{-1}[U]$’s are open if I’m not assuming it in the first place? Apologies if this is a stupid question I couldn’t find an answer to this from the wiki [page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology). They’re not stating anything about continuity in the definition section.

Also isn’t the main idea here that I would be constructing a continuous function by inducing the topology? It seems odd that I would have to assume it. Quoting wikipedia

> an induced topology on a topological space is a topology that *makes* a given (inducing) function or collection of functions continuous from this topological space.

Answer (score 1):

The point is the following: You aren't *given* a topology on $X$ here. $X$ is just a bare set. By
$$ \tau_X := \{f^{-1}[U] : U \in \tau_Y \}$$
you are *defining* a topology (have you checked that this set is actually a topology on $X$?). Therefore is does not make sense to ask, whether these sets are open in $X$, because we are defining them to be the open sets in $X$.

Comment: So the sets are open since $U_i \in \tau_X$ we have that $$\bigcup_i U_i = \bigcup_i  f^{-1}[V_i] =  f^{-1}[\bigcup_i  V_i]$$ and since a similar argument can be made for the finite intersection and $f^{-1}[Y] = X, f^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$?

Comment: @Wondera And $f^{-1}[U]$ **has to be** open in the new topology on $X$ anyway, because we want $f$ to be continuous from $(X,\tau_X) \to (Y, \tau_Y)$, so these sets are the minimal collection we need and because they luckily already are a topology we can stop there: we have fulfilled the minimal condition and $\tau_X$ is the *smallest* topology possible that makes $f$ continuous.